# Add TeX input method shortcuts to C-x 8 map

Tags: input-method

I really like the TeX input method. It makes typing symbols a breeze, since years of LaTeX have worked the symbols into my muscle memory.

However, input methods have their quirks (like not working with `key-chord`s), and I'd rather not leave it on all the time.

I also like the `iso-transl` <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>8</kbd> map. It's handy because it's always there and very unintrusive. However, it has a rather small vocabulary of symbols, and I can never remember their keys.

Is there any way I can either

- bind a command to <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>8</kbd> <kbd>\</kbd> that will prompt for a name from the `TeX` input method and insert it, even if the `TeX` input method is not active
- Temporarily enable the `TeX` IM for one character only.

Answer (score 2):

If I need to enter a symbol I use `C-\` then enter `TeX` as input mode. After that I can use `C-\` to toggle between regular input and "TeX-style" input.

Comment: That's what I'm using right now. I'd rather not have to remember to toggle back, because I'm terribly lazy.

Comment: Ah. That lazy huh ;-). Then I don't think I can help you...

Comment: It's partly saving the physical effort, and partly the mental overhead of tracking yet another fragment of state about my current environment. When I toggle input methods, I usually set it and forget.

Comment: I'm using Smart-mode-line (https://github.com/Bruce-Connor/smart-mode-line) and then the TeX input mode shows up as a `\\`.